# Enabling Selinux on debian-based system

Tags: linux, debian, selinux, parrot-os

I just want to know if there is a way to enable SElinux on a Debian-based system. I'm currently running parrot OS with what a think is Debian 10 and I'm having problem enabling Selinux on it. When I run `sudo selinux-activate` it says to boot the machine but when I do nothing is enabled. I don't know if it might be because it's not be compatible with Debian. I already uninstalled App armor by the way.

here is the output of `check-selinux-installation`

```
getfilecon:  getfilecon(/proc/1) failed:  Operation not supported
SELinux is not enabled.
Could not read the domain of PID 1.
The directories /sys/fs/selinux and /selinux are missing.
```

hope someone can help me.

Comment: Have you folowed the installation instructions found in [SELinux/Setup](https://wiki.debian.org/SELinux/Setup)?